# Removing on keyup from jQuery search script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a jQuery search script which uses the on keyup function to submit the query. How can I make it search when the user presses enter?

Here is my current code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#search").keyup(function(){
        var search=$(this).val();
        var query=encodeURIComponent(search);
        var yt_url='search.php?q='+query+'&page=1';
        window.location.hash='search/'+query+'/1/';
        document.title=$(this).val()+" - My Search Script";
        $.ajax({
            type:"GET",
            url:yt_url,
            dataType:"html",
            success:function(response){
                $("#result").html(response);
            }
        });
    });
    if(window.location.hash.indexOf('#search/')==0){
        query=window.location.hash.replace('#search/', '').replace('/1/', '');
        $('#search').val(decodeURIComponent(query)).keyup();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general case

```
    $(document).keyup(function( e ) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            // execute your code
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

#search_form must be id of `<form>` !

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#search_form").submit(function(){
        var search=$("#search").val();
        var query=encodeURIComponent(search);
        var yt_url='search.php?q='+query+'&page=1';
        window.location.hash='search/'+query+'/1/';
        document.title=search+" - My Search Script";
        $.ajax({
            type:"GET",
            url:yt_url,
            dataType:"html",
            success:function(response){
                $("#result").html(response);
            }
        });
    });
    if(window.location.hash.indexOf('#search/')==0){
        query=window.location.hash.replace('#search/', '').replace('/1/', '');
        $('#search').val(decodeURIComponent(query)).keyup();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found that I need to do this, have 2 events, one that caters for the enter key and one that ignores the keypress:

```
jQuery('#search').keydown(function (e) {
                if (e.which == 13) {
                    // Do you work here
                }
            });
            jQuery('#search').keypress(function (e) {
                if (e.which == 13) {
                    return false;
                }
            });
```